# Using powershell to run diskpart commands

Tags: powershell, diskpart

Although there is a `Get-Disk` cmdlet in PowerShell, it is not recognized as a command in PowerShell 2.0 on Windows 7. So, I use the diskpart command with the following as an example:

```
DiskPart
List disk
Select disk 1
Clean
Create partition primary
Select partition 1
Active
Format FS=NTFS quick
Assign
```

I want to know if I can write those lines to a text file and then use PowerShell to execute them. I couldn't find a handy guide for that. How can I use PowerShell to run Win32 commands?

Comment: The last time I checked you can install both [PowerShell 7.x](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-7.1) and [PowerShell 5.1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/install/windows-powershell-system-requirements?view=powershell-7.1) on Windows 7 and either one of those versions should have the necessary modules.  Without updating PowerShell to at least 5.1 you won't be able to do what you want outside of DiskPart. [Download PS 7.x](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell)

Comment: @ramhound that should be an answer since it's the only real answer to the question.

Comment: @FlorianHeigl - There already is an accepted answer to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a relevant document from Microsoft: [diskpart scripts and examples](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart-scripts-and-examples).

> Use `diskpart /s` to run scripts that automate disk-related tasks, such as creating volumes or converting disks to dynamic disks. [...]
>
> To create a diskpart script, create a text file that contains the Diskpart commands that you want to run, with one command per line, and no empty lines. You can start a line with `rem` to make the line a comment. For example, here's a script that wipes a disk and then creates a 300 MB partition for the Windows Recovery Environment:
>
> ```
> select disk 0
> clean
> convert gpt
> create partition primary size=300
> format quick fs=ntfs label=Windows RE tools
> assign letter=T
> ```
>
> To run a diskpart script, at the command prompt, type the following command, where *scriptname* is the name of the text file that contains your script:
>
> ```
> diskpart /s scriptname.txt
> ```

Comment: Yes that is possible to use that file in diskpart. I was wondering if I can execute that remotely via powershell.

Comment: @mahmood I can't find this requirement mentioned anywhere in your question. You should edit it. Make sure to mention all relevant details.

Comment: @gronostaj "How can use PowerShell to run win32 commands?" - However, I would argue you have already answered that, since it should be as simple as a PowerShell script that executes `diskpart /s scriptname.txt`

Comment: @Ramhound I meant the "remotely" part. I'm not familiar with how PS works in that regard.

Comment: OK. The remote command execution is `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $RemoteMachine -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock { diskpart /s c:\diskman.txt }`